# Rendering a java map for use in reactjs

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, spring-boot

A reactjs fetch call into my springboot api returns in this format map> 
ie

```
Key : "test", Value : [
  {
    "fieldLocation": "aa.java",
    "fieldName": "bb"
  },
  {
    "fieldLocation": "bb.java",
    "fieldName": "cc"
  },
  {
    "fieldLocation": "cc.java",
    "fieldName": "dd"
  },
  {
    "fieldLocation": "dd.java",
    "fieldName": "tt"
  }
]
```

Im not sure how i can render this data map into reactjs table , note that the value array could be varying lengths

Comment: You can get the value from the "Value" field and convert it into a JSON with json.parse() and then use can use the result to map the data into table rows. result.map((data) => <tr>{data}</td>)

Comment: The array in `Value` would be usable. Because that contains an `Array` which contains several `Objects`.

Comment: So if i have test2 and test 3 records aswell as test above , how can i store this from the fetch call and how to display this information in a table